# ffmpeg-python extracting frames from camera in batches

Tags: python, ffmpeg

When I read frames from my camera using ffmpeg-python, the frames appear to come in batches of 4- why is this, and how can I change it?

I would like to get one frame at a time... I'm also hoping to avoid faking the frame times using the `-r` option

[image]

In the image above, I'm recording at 30fps. The ~120ms pause followed by 3 quick frames suggests that the frames are coming in batches of 4.

Partial code

```py
reader = (ffmpeg
    .input('/dev/video0', framerate=fps)
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24')
    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True))
    
while True:
    start = time.time_ns()
    frame = reader.stdout.read(width * height * 3)
    logger.debug(f'frame read time: {(time.time_ns() - start)/1e6}ms')
    # Do something else
    logger.debug(f'frame capture loop: {(time.time_ns() - start)/1e6}ms')
```

Comment: It could be related to the ratio of B-frames and P-frames in the encoded video stream. Do you know the video codec? Can you control the video codec parameters of the camera?

Comment: Is that like the pixel format? I get `YUYV 4:2:2` from running `v4l2-ctl -V`.

Comment: No, I am asking about the video codec (like H.264 or H.265 or MJPG...) and codec parameters. Do you know what video codec that the camera is using?