# Rasp Pi Python can you record a video and save individual frames at the same time

Tags: python, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I am looking to record a video and save the frames at the same time. I am currently using the following line to record the video:
`

```
def capture_video():
    cmd2 = subprocess.Popen(['libcamera-vid', '-t', str(duration), '--width', '1920', '--height', '1080', '--nopreview', '-o', '/home/pi/robotic_eyes_platform/output/test.h264'])
```

`
Please let me know if there is a way to save the individual frames at the same time.

Is there a way to add some commands to that line to capture and save the frames?

Comment: yes, you can, but not if you leave the recording to a separate program. Get your frames from the camera in your own program, and push them through a video encoder on one hand and save individual frames. don't see the point though: you're just producing duplicate data, and at these resolutions, you might have a hard time keeping up with the write rate to the SD card if you're not using video compression to reduce the amount of data you're saving.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Do you know what line of code would be able to use this?

Comment: you need to write a program to do that, not just a single line of code. Tools you might use could be things like [ffmpeg-python](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/), where you could simply open an V4L2 input stream (aka camera), run that into an H264 encoder chain, as well as pushing it through whatever you want to do with the individual frames. Again, you will *not* have a good time if you try to write frames to disk at the same rate you're encoding them as video. Your SD card stands a high chance of not being able to keep up. Write a raw frame every couple of seconds? Sure.

Comment: See, as an example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68159702/ffmpeg-python-extracting-frames-from-camera-in-batches